# Newsletter Template - Display table properly

Tags: html, css

I am creating a newsletter template with a table.

I would like to fix the table.

My idea was to use, `<div style="overflow-x: auto;">` around the table, but I do not get any change.

Find below my current template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0081)http://test.com/newsletter/daily-newsletter-test-market-0400-66/?frame=0 -->
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <title>Daily newsletter for 10/19/2020 - test.com</title>
  <!--[if mso]>   <xml>     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>       <o:AllowPNG/>       <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>     </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>   </xml>   <style>     table {border-collapse: collapse;}     .spacer,.divider {mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}     td,th,div,p,a {font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;}     td,th,div,p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family:"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}   </style>   <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Open+Sans');
    @media only screen {
      .col,
      td,
      th,
      div,
      p {
        font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .webfont {
        font-family: "Lato", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .underline {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    #outlook a,
    .links-inherit-color a {
      padding: 0;
      color: inherit;
    }
    
    img {
      border: 0;
      line-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .col {
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 22px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .hover-scale:hover {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    
    .video {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .star:hover a,
    .star:hover~.star a {
      color: #FFCF0F!important;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .video {
        width: 100%;
      }
      u~div .wrapper {
        min-width: 100vw;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100%!important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .col {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block!important;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      .col-sm-1 {
        max-width: 25%;
      }
      .col-sm-2 {
        max-width: 50%;
      }
      .col-sm-3 {
        max-width: 75%;
      }
      .col-sm-third {
        max-width: 33.33333%;
      }
      .col-sm-auto {
        width: auto!important;
      }
      .col-sm-push-1 {
        margin-left: 25%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-2 {
        margin-left: 50%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-3 {
        margin-left: 75%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-third {
        margin-left: 33.33333%;
      }
      .full-width-sm {
        display: table!important;
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-first {
        display: table-header-group!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-last {
        display: table-footer-group!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-top {
        display: table-caption!important;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .toggle-content {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        transition: max-height .4s linear;
        -webkit-transition: max-height .4s linear;
      }
      .toggle-trigger:hover+.toggle-content,
      .toggle-content:hover {
        max-height: 999px!important;
      }
      .show-sm {
        display: inherit!important;
        font-size: inherit!important;
        line-height: inherit!important;
        max-height: none!important;
      }
      .hide-sm {
        display: none!important;
      }
      .align-sm-center {
        display: table!important;
        float: none;
        margin-left: auto!important;
        margin-right: auto!important;
      }
      .align-sm-left {
        float: left;
      }
      .align-sm-right {
        float: right;
      }
      .text-sm-center {
        text-align: center!important;
      }
      .text-sm-left {
        text-align: left!important;
      }
      .text-sm-right {
        text-align: right!important;
      }
      .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item {
        display: block!important;
      }
      .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 0!important;
      }
      .h1 {
        font-size: 32px!important;
      }
      .h2 {
        font-size: 24px!important;
      }
      .h3 {
        font-size: 16px!important;
      }
      .borderless-sm {
        border: none!important;
      }
      .height-sm-auto {
        height: auto!important;
      }
      .line-height-sm-0 {
        line-height: 0!important;
      }
      .overlay-sm-bg {
        background: #232323;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
      u~div .wrapper .toggle-trigger {
        display: none!important;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .toggle-content {
        max-height: none;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .nav-item {
        display: inline-block!important;
        padding: 0 10px!important;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item {
        display: block!important;
      }
      .p-sm-0 {
        padding: 0!important;
      }
      .p-sm-8 {
        padding: 8px!important;
      }
      .p-sm-16 {
        padding: 16px!important;
      }
      .p-sm-24 {
        padding: 24px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-0 {
        padding-top: 0!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-8 {
        padding-top: 8px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-16 {
        padding-top: 16px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-24 {
        padding-top: 24px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-0 {
        padding-right: 0!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-8 {
        padding-right: 8px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-16 {
        padding-right: 16px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-24 {
        padding-right: 24px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-0 {
        padding-bottom: 0!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-8 {
        padding-bottom: 8px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-16 {
        padding-bottom: 16px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-24 {
        padding-bottom: 24px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-0 {
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-8 {
        padding-left: 8px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-16 {
        padding-left: 16px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-24 {
        padding-left: 24px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-0 {
        padding-right: 0!important;
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .px-sm-8 {
        padding-right: 8px!important;
        padding-left: 8px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-16 {
        padding-right: 16px!important;
        padding-left: 16px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-24 {
        padding-right: 24px!important;
        padding-left: 24px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-0 {
        padding-top: 0!important;
        padding-bottom: 0!important;
      }
      .py-sm-8 {
        padding-top: 8px!important;
        padding-bottom: 8px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-16 {
        padding-top: 16px!important;
        padding-bottom: 16px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-24 {
        padding-top: 24px!important;
        padding-bottom: 24px!important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;word-break:break-word;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;">
  <div style="display:none;font-size:0;line-height:0;"></div>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center">
          <table class="container" role="presentation" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="px-sm-8" style="padding: 0 24px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left">
                  <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col" style="padding: 0 8px;" width="100%">
                          <h1>Buying/Selling for Mon, October 19th<br></h1>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center">
          <table class="container" role="presentation" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="px-sm-8" style="padding: 0 24px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left">
                  <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col" style="padding: 0 8px;" width="100%">
                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse" width="100%" id="overall-table" class="plan" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr valign="middle" label="Header">
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Name</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Owner</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Company</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="middle">Amount</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="right">Transaction Date</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test Company<br> (LDP)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-24</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Joon<br>Wydenhauer</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Child</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Netflix, Inc. (NASDAQ)<br> (NFLX)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-23</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test Company<br> (LDP)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test2 Company<br> (WIW)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Tom<br>Larp</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Aberdeen Ultra Short Municipal Income Fund Class A<br> (ATOAX)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div class="spacer line-height-sm-0 py-sm-8" style="line-height: 24px;">‌</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="a11y-speak-polite" class="a11y-speak-region" style="position: absolute;margin: -1px;padding: 0;height: 1px;width: 1px;overflow: hidden;clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);-webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);clip-path: inset(50%);border: 0;word-wrap: normal !important;"
    aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions text" aria-atomic="true"></div>
  <div id="a11y-speak-assertive" class="a11y-speak-region" style="position: absolute;margin: -1px;padding: 0;height: 1px;width: 1px;overflow: hidden;clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);-webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);clip-path: inset(50%);border: 0;word-wrap: normal !important;"
    aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions text" aria-atomic="true"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions how to display the data properly?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Do you want to show it like this? https://nimb.ws/6KZLV9

Comment: @m4n0 Yes exactly! So that all words can easily be read.

Comment: You just need to replace the table width attribute value to 600+. 800 as in my image.

Comment: @m4n0 Please post your solution. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace table `width` attribute value from `600` to something that is preferrable. `800` worked fine for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0081)http://test.com/newsletter/daily-newsletter-test-market-0400-66/?frame=0 -->
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <title>Daily newsletter for 10/19/2020 - test.com</title>
  <!--[if mso]>   <xml>     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>       <o:AllowPNG/>       <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>     </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>   </xml>   <style>     table {border-collapse: collapse;}     .spacer,.divider {mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}     td,th,div,p,a {font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;}     td,th,div,p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family:"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}   </style>   <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Open+Sans');
    @media only screen {
      .col,
      td,
      th,
      div,
      p {
        font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .webfont {
        font-family: "Lato", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .underline {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    #outlook a,
    .links-inherit-color a {
      padding: 0;
      color: inherit;
    }
    
    img {
      border: 0;
      line-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .col {
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 22px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .hover-scale:hover {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    
    .video {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .star:hover a,
    .star:hover~.star a {
      color: #FFCF0F!important;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .video {
        width: 100%;
      }
      u~div .wrapper {
        min-width: 100vw;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100%!important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .col {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block!important;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      .col-sm-1 {
        max-width: 25%;
      }
      .col-sm-2 {
        max-width: 50%;
      }
      .col-sm-3 {
        max-width: 75%;
      }
      .col-sm-third {
        max-width: 33.33333%;
      }
      .col-sm-auto {
        width: auto!important;
      }
      .col-sm-push-1 {
        margin-left: 25%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-2 {
        margin-left: 50%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-3 {
        margin-left: 75%;
      }
      .col-sm-push-third {
        margin-left: 33.33333%;
      }
      .full-width-sm {
        display: table!important;
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-first {
        display: table-header-group!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-last {
        display: table-footer-group!important;
      }
      .stack-sm-top {
        display: table-caption!important;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .toggle-content {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        transition: max-height .4s linear;
        -webkit-transition: max-height .4s linear;
      }
      .toggle-trigger:hover+.toggle-content,
      .toggle-content:hover {
        max-height: 999px!important;
      }
      .show-sm {
        display: inherit!important;
        font-size: inherit!important;
        line-height: inherit!important;
        max-height: none!important;
      }
      .hide-sm {
        display: none!important;
      }
      .align-sm-center {
        display: table!important;
        float: none;
        margin-left: auto!important;
        margin-right: auto!important;
      }
      .align-sm-left {
        float: left;
      }
      .align-sm-right {
        float: right;
      }
      .text-sm-center {
        text-align: center!important;
      }
      .text-sm-left {
        text-align: left!important;
      }
      .text-sm-right {
        text-align: right!important;
      }
      .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item {
        display: block!important;
      }
      .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 0!important;
      }
      .h1 {
        font-size: 32px!important;
      }
      .h2 {
        font-size: 24px!important;
      }
      .h3 {
        font-size: 16px!important;
      }
      .borderless-sm {
        border: none!important;
      }
      .height-sm-auto {
        height: auto!important;
      }
      .line-height-sm-0 {
        line-height: 0!important;
      }
      .overlay-sm-bg {
        background: #232323;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
      u~div .wrapper .toggle-trigger {
        display: none!important;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .toggle-content {
        max-height: none;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .nav-item {
        display: inline-block!important;
        padding: 0 10px!important;
      }
      u~div .wrapper .nav-sm-vertical .nav-item {
        display: block!important;
      }
      .p-sm-0 {
        padding: 0!important;
      }
      .p-sm-8 {
        padding: 8px!important;
      }
      .p-sm-16 {
        padding: 16px!important;
      }
      .p-sm-24 {
        padding: 24px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-0 {
        padding-top: 0!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-8 {
        padding-top: 8px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-16 {
        padding-top: 16px!important;
      }
      .pt-sm-24 {
        padding-top: 24px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-0 {
        padding-right: 0!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-8 {
        padding-right: 8px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-16 {
        padding-right: 16px!important;
      }
      .pr-sm-24 {
        padding-right: 24px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-0 {
        padding-bottom: 0!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-8 {
        padding-bottom: 8px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-16 {
        padding-bottom: 16px!important;
      }
      .pb-sm-24 {
        padding-bottom: 24px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-0 {
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-8 {
        padding-left: 8px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-16 {
        padding-left: 16px!important;
      }
      .pl-sm-24 {
        padding-left: 24px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-0 {
        padding-right: 0!important;
        padding-left: 0!important;
      }
      .px-sm-8 {
        padding-right: 8px!important;
        padding-left: 8px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-16 {
        padding-right: 16px!important;
        padding-left: 16px!important;
      }
      .px-sm-24 {
        padding-right: 24px!important;
        padding-left: 24px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-0 {
        padding-top: 0!important;
        padding-bottom: 0!important;
      }
      .py-sm-8 {
        padding-top: 8px!important;
        padding-bottom: 8px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-16 {
        padding-top: 16px!important;
        padding-bottom: 16px!important;
      }
      .py-sm-24 {
        padding-top: 24px!important;
        padding-bottom: 24px!important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;word-break:break-word;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;">
  <div style="display:none;font-size:0;line-height:0;"></div>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center">
          <table class="container" role="presentation" width="800" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="px-sm-8" style="padding: 0 24px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left">
                  <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col" style="padding: 0 8px;" width="100%">
                          <h1>Buying/Selling for Mon, October 19th<br></h1>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="wrapper" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="px-sm-16" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="center">
          <table class="container" role="presentation" width="800" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="px-sm-8" style="padding: 0 24px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left">
                  <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col" style="padding: 0 8px;" width="100%">
                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse" width="100%" id="overall-table" class="plan" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr valign="middle" label="Header">
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Name</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Owner</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="left">Company</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="middle">Amount</th>
                                <th style="padding:2px" repeatable="" align="right">Transaction Date</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test Company<br> (LDP)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-24</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Joon<br>Wydenhauer</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Child</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Netflix, Inc. (NASDAQ)<br> (NFLX)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-23</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test Company<br> (LDP)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Thomas<br>Arplander</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Test2 Company<br> (WIW)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" valign="middle" repeatable="" label="Row">
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Tom<br>Larp</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Wife</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="left">Aberdeen Ultra Short Municipal Income Fund Class A<br> (ATOAX)</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" align="middle">0</td>
                                <td style="padding:2px" class="last" align="right">2020-09-22</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div class="spacer line-height-sm-0 py-sm-8" style="line-height: 24px;">‌</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="a11y-speak-polite" class="a11y-speak-region" style="position: absolute;margin: -1px;padding: 0;height: 1px;width: 1px;overflow: hidden;clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);-webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);clip-path: inset(50%);border: 0;word-wrap: normal !important;"
    aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions text" aria-atomic="true"></div>
  <div id="a11y-speak-assertive" class="a11y-speak-region" style="position: absolute;margin: -1px;padding: 0;height: 1px;width: 1px;overflow: hidden;clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);-webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);clip-path: inset(50%);border: 0;word-wrap: normal !important;"
    aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions text" aria-atomic="true"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix it when being on a smartphone. The table becomes unreadable if I am resizing it into responsive. Appreciate your reply!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww?editors=1100

Comment: Yes! Looks really good! Can you add it to the above example? Highly appreciate your help!!!

Comment: You can check the documentation in the code or else please read this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/01/table-design-patterns-web/